# How to name a JSON?

Tags: java, json

This is my code

```
    List<Object[]> list = query.list();
    List<JSONObject> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object[] rows : list) {
        String buildingId = rows[0].toString();
        String floorId = rows[1].toString();
        String routerId = rows[2].toString();
        String routerName = rows[3].toString();

        Map<String, List<String>> floorMap = buildingMap.get(buildingId);
        if(floorMap == null) {
            floorMap = new HashMap<>();
        }
       ......
    }
```

What i need JSON format is like this

```
"buildings":{
"building_id":"3"={
        "floor_id":"21"=[
            "router_id":"3"
        ]
    },
"building_id":"2"={
        "floor_id":"20"=[
            "router_id":"1101",
            "router_id":"1102",
            "router_id":"0",
            "router_id":"1104",
            "router_id":"1106"
        ],
        "floor_id":"17"=[
            "router_id":"1111",
            "router_id":"1112",
            "router_id":"1113"
        ]
    },
 "building_id":"1"={
      "floor_id":"10"=[
           "router_id":"1"
        ]
    }
}
```

But now i'm getting like this

```
{
3={
    21=[
        3
    ]
},
2={
    20=[
        1101,
        1102,
        0,
        1104,
        1106
    ],
    17=[
        1111,
        1112,
        1113,

    ]
},
1={
    10=[
        1
    ]
}
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using Java then you may try Gson API for such conversions. You may need one POJO and GSON .

Comment: Your expected JSON is invalid, and your code doesn't produce anything at all. It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Object[]> list = query.list();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // convert your list to json
    String jsonList = gson.toJson(list);
```

you need Gson Jar and simply you can convert list into json string.

Answer (score -1):

My senior gave this code and finally it worked for me

```
`@Override
public String getFullRouterList() throws Exception {

    //Format
    // -- building map with building_id and floor map
    // -- floor map with floor_id and list of routers

    Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> buildingMap = new HashMap<>();

    System.out.println("in dao of getFullRouterList ");
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    String sql = "SELECT building_id, floor_id, router_id, router_name FROM iot_trackbit.router_details";
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

    List<Object[]> list = query.list();
    List<JSONArray> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object[] rows : list) {
        String buildingId = rows[0].toString();
        String floorId = rows[1].toString();
        String routerId = rows[2].toString();
        String routerName = rows[3].toString();

        Map<String, List<String>> floorMap = buildingMap.get(buildingId);
        if(floorMap == null) {
            floorMap = new HashMap<>();
        }

        List<String> routerList = floorMap.get(floorId);
        if(routerList == null) {
            routerList = new ArrayList<>();             
        }

        routerList.add(routerId);
        floorMap.put(floorId, routerList);
        buildingMap.put(buildingId, floorMap);

        System.out.println(buildingMap.keySet());
        System.out.println(buildingMap);            

    }

    JSONObject finalObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray buildingsArr = new JSONArray();

    for(String buildingId : buildingMap.keySet()) {
        JSONObject buildingObject = new JSONObject();
        Map<String, List<String>> floorMap = (HashMap<String, List<String>>) buildingMap.get(buildingId);

        //{"1":["router1","router2","router3"]}     
        JSONArray floorsArr = new JSONArray();
        for(String floorId : floorMap.keySet()) {
            JSONObject floorObject = new JSONObject();
            List<String> routerList = floorMap.get(floorId);

            //["router1","router2"]
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            for(String routerId : routerList) {
                JSONObject routerObj = new JSONObject();

                    routerObj.put("id",routerId);                   
                    array.add(routerObj);
            }
            floorObject.put("id",floorId);
            floorObject.put("routers", array);
            floorsArr.add(floorObject);
        }

        buildingObject.put("id", buildingId);
        buildingObject.put("floors", floorsArr);//floors array
        buildingsArr.add(buildingObject);

        finalObj.put("buildings",buildingsArr);
    }


    System.out.println("finalObj.toJSONString() : " +finalObj.toJSONString());

    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return finalObj.toJSONString();
```

}`

Now i`m geting like this format`
{
    "buildings": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "floors": [
                {
                    "id": "21",
                    "routers": [
                        {
                            "id": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "23",
                    "routers": [
                        {
                            "id": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "gateway123"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1001"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1002"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1003"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "floors": [
                {
                    "id": "20",
                    "routers": [
                        {
                            "id": "1101"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1102"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1104"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1106"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1107"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1111"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1109"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1110"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "17",
                    "routers": [
                        {
                            "id": "1111"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1112"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1113"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1114"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1115"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1116"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1117"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1118"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "g1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "1119"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "18",
                    "routers": [
                        {
                            "id": "010101"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "floors": [
                {
                    "id": "10",
                    "routers": [
                        {
                            "id": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`
Thanks for all